# Can I make a MySQL var equal to a MySQL command?

Tags: php, mysql

If I perform the following MySQL query through PHP:

```
UPDATE pictures 
        SET category = '0'
        WHERE category = '$categoryID'
        AND username = '$username'";
$queryUncat = mysql_query($uncategorise) or die(mysql_error());
```

It works fine and any category that was equal to $categoryID gets changed to 0. However, if I perform the following:

```
UPDATE pictures 
        SET category = '0',
        pictureorder = (SELECT COUNT(category) + 1 WHERE category='0' AND username='$username')
        WHERE category = '$categoryID'
        AND username = '$username'";
$queryUncat = mysql_query($uncategorise) or die(mysql_error());
```

Not only does *pictureorder* not equal to the `count` of the *category* row plus one, but the *category* no longer gets changed if equal to *$categoryID*. I'm not too good at figuring this out as I know only basic MySQL through PHP and am not familiar with it through its own console.

Thanks in advance for any suggestions.

Comment: That's something you have to work on then. You need to learn SQL and send the right query. Work on it in the console with hand written values, then once you have it working correctly, copy it into your PHP code and add the variables.

Comment: This would give you syntax error. That's way nothing gets changed.

Comment: Dan: HTML is some side-work in my career, PHP less, and SQL even less so again so it would be a poor career choice for me to dedicate enough time to SQL to know it thoroughly. That said, your advice is very true. Thanks. 

Ypercube: Thanks. I needed confirmation of that. It was a piece of code recommended by someone else and I believed that the syntax was wrong but didn't know SQL thoroughly enough to confirm so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This form of query is not valid. First, your subquery is missing a `FROM` clause. Second, you cannot select from the same table you are updating in the same query.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/update.html

Comment: To expand on what I mentioned in a previous comment: This was a break-away question for a previous problem I had where this solution was recommended. I was having no luck pushing a discussion on it there and my research couldn't confirm if the syntax was wrong but I suspected it was. Thanks for confirming so, Dan, and why.